# What if maven artifact not anymore available?

Tags: maven, artifact

As we just migrated all projects to maven projects, one question came up and I couldn't find any suitable solutions yet.

What if maven shuts down forever or just one artifact is not available anymore? Or what if some versions are not available anymore, and the software cannot run with the newer ones?

Since we're not hosting a copy of the artifacts locally, should we host copies of every jar somewhere for such a scenario?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlikely, but if you build your artifacts with Maven, you already have a copy of each relevant artifact - in your local repository. If you backup it from time to time, you have the necessary level of security.

Alternatively, use a company repository manager (Nexus/Artifactory) to proxy MavenCentral. It will also keep copies of the used artifacts.

Comment: Best is to install a repository manager within the company...and make there backup's from..as @JF Meier suggested...